# How to use NSDateFormatter to convert?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

There is a string like

```
00:09:000
```

Which is minutes:seconds:ms

How to use NSDateFormatter to convert this string to NSDate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use this to convert a date to a string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy H:m:ss"];
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormat release];
```

to find out the date format you need to use (for seconds and milliseconds) in `setDateFormat` check out the [unicode reference site](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: have you inserted the correct formatting in the setDateFormat call? you need to check out the unicode reference and don't forget to include all formatting such as colons